# open image put in stream and save it

Tags: c#, bitmap

I don't know why this give me an error, I open the picture and then I pu it in the stream and then i save the stream picture with another name, pretty simple

```
        string pic = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        string filePath;

        filePath = pic;

        Bitmap bmp = null;



      //   Create from a stream so we don't keep a lock on the file.
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
        }


        bmp.Save(pic + "sdf.jpg");
```

Comment: What's the exception? What's the exception message?

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.110).aspx): _You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap._

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your code as following,

```
         if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
              string pic = openFileDialog1.FileName;
              string filePath;
              string newfilepath;//here you should assign your newfilepath
              filePath = pic;
              Bitmap bmp = null;

              using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                    {
                     bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
                     bmp.Save(newfilepath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);//here you can change the format i.e. bmp,jpg,png etc.

                    }
           }
```

Hope these help.